# TextScaleFactor for TextField in Flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter, widget, textfield

Was wondering is there a way to control textscalefactor for TextField widget in flutter.  Basically I want to limit a text field from growing too large when a user increase font/text size in their devices accessibility settings.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can wrap it with a `MediaQuery` with a custom `textScaleFactor`

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final mqData = MediaQuery.of(context);
  final mqDataNew = mqData.copyWith(textScaleFactor: mqData.textScaleFactor > 5.0 ? 5.0 : mqData.textScaleFactor)
  return MediaQuery(data: mqDataNew, child: TextField());
}
```

The `TextField` does not need to be a direct child of `MediaQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set lower and upper bounds for the textScaleFactor of your entire app.

```
return MaterialApp(
   builder: (context, child) {
      const lowerLimit = 1.0;
      const upperLimit = 1.2;

      final mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);          
      final scale = mediaQueryData.textScaleFactor.clamp(lowerLimit, upperLimit);
      return MediaQuery(
          child: child,
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: scale),
      );
   },
);
```