# How to use textscalefactor in textformfield in flutter to restrict text size?

Tags: flutter

textScaleFactor : -

```
textScaleFactor: 1.0
```

How to use TextFormField in flutter to fix text size for all type of resolution ?

Comment: I think you are looking for this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66668724/1318946

Comment: No. For that I have pass context in my entire project and also have to use material app. I have taken common widget and used in 206 screens. So I cant do that

Comment: In Text widget we simply pass textScaleFactor: 1.0 property to restrict size. In a same way can we use that in text form field ? or any other way ?

Comment: You have to post the custom widget that you have created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TextScaleFactor for TextField in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54581400/textscalefactor-for-textfield-in-flutter)

Comment: Yes. Kind of that. But in that I have to pass context to use. Actually I have made global widget to use in entire project. So, I just pass constant mediaquery to use it. And It is working fine. But Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `TextFormField` with `MediaQuery` like so.

```dart
MediaQuery(
    data: const MediaQueryData(textScaleFactor: 2.0),
    child: TextFormField(),
),
```